# Which to use? GIF or Image

Tags: website-design

Here's the link to a web page I made - https://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~saicharan/graphics/assign1/report.html

It describes a code I wrote. The code loads one of the 3 shapes and user can rotate/translate them. I have added the images of shapes I included in the code.

My question is - Should I just put the images or Should I put up gif showing the rotation and translations of objects?

I always feel that GIFs are kind of kiddish and website looses its classy look. So I just use images always. Any other suggestions/views?

Comment: GIFs **are** images... your question doesn't make sense!

Comment: @curiousdannii I think what he means is animated images.

Comment: You're essentially asking for a site review in this question, which is not allowed on this site.  If you have a general UX question, that other people can benefit from, please ask that.

Comment: @JohnGB - I am asking a general UX question only. Would using GIF's make any webpage appear less serious and kiddish?

Comment: @SashankGondala That wasn't the question you asked, but even if you had, it would most likely have been off-topic on account of it being primarily opinion based.  I suggest you take a look at what makes a good question by reading the FAQ on this site, and by looking at some other questions.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the requirements. Motoin on page is a best way to get attention on things where we want our user to focus , on the other hand they may be distracting in some cases. But sometime you have to show the motion to give the user more clear idea as in your case.

I suggest you to use a combination of both as continues rotation/motion of pictures on a page may be distrating or annoying sometimes. You can put simple image and on hovering mouse you can show the animated gif (i.e. to show what should it look like). I think it would be a better work around instead of using just .jpg or .gif alone.
Hope you can get some idea from it.